# javascript / jquery slider(carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm creating an iphone (web)app.
If user slides tumb left it has to show the settings panel, after modifying settings, user drags thumb to the right and the normal app screen comes back.

However I took as basis some carrousel code which needs (minimal) 3 pages, I only want 2 pages.

Current state:
http://jsfiddle.net/U92wt/

I can't remove the red page without breaking everything....

Edit:
More information about code used [here](http://cubiq.org/swipeview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried cruising through your code but I couldn't identify exactly what the issue was. It's a good idea and I felt like playing around with it so I wrote an implementation that is capable of only two panels that you're welcome to use if you wish.

http://www.netortech.com/plugins/swiper.htm

If you like it please give me a vote on the jQuery website!

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CarouselSwiper

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much!. Registered an account to upvote.